# Displaying a Digitial Elevation Model using GRASS GIS draped by an RGB Raster

Tags: grass-gis, dem, rendering

I have the following:

1. Digital Elevation Model from SRTM
2. LANDSAT Imagery from the same area

I wish to display the DEM draped with the raster band combination (3,2,1) using GRASS GIS.

My attempts to use:

a. Create `r.composite` and then use it as an input to the color model for NVIS results in a B/W rendering of the raster surface.

b. Creating a VTK ASCII file using `r.out.vtk` is confusing as there is a confusion what is an input image and what is an rgbmap (created using the RED, GREEN and BLUE) bands of LANDSAT. There is of course no issue with the elevation data. However using `paraview` to display the output file `data.vtk` fails (does not work).

Comment: You can use NVIZ for this rather than VTK. See screenshot in http://grass.osgeo.org/screenshots/3D/ --> "Perspective Landsat TM RGB visualization". Be sure to resample first with bilinear method the SRTM DEM to the higher Landsat resolution, then drape...

Answer (score 1):

Set up your region in a UTM projection and project all DEM and the RGB raster(`r.composite`output) in UTM as well. This will allow grass GIS to render your RGB raster on top of the DEM.